# I am getting Segmentation fault while reversing vectors without using STL

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, c++17

I am unable to use below code to reverse a vector although reversing array works.
Please look at it at the earliest as i am unable to do it properly.
In arrays i use static while returning and return a pointer function but here i am not able to figure out.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;


    vector<int> reversearray(vector<int> a,int n)
    {
        int low=0, high=n-1;

        while(low<high)
        {
            swap(a[low],a[high]);
            low++;
            high--;
        }

        return a;


    }
    int main() {

        int t,n;
        vector<int> v,ans;
        cin>>t;
        while(t--)
        {
            cin>>n;

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                cin>>v[i];
            }

            ans=reversearray(v,n);
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                cout<<ans[i]<<" ";
            //Simple solution would be to iterate in reverse order
            /*for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
                cout<<v[i]<<" ";
            }*/
           cout<<"\n";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are getting segmentation fault is that you are trying to access the uninitiated memory.

You cannot directly scan in the input to `v[i]` because the size of vector `v` is 0 initially.

Instead use `push_back()` method or initialise or resize the vector to the  size `n`.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> reversearray(std::vector<int> a,int n)
{
    int low=0, high=n-1;

    while(low<high)
    {
        std::swap(a[low],a[high]);
        low++;
        high--;a
    }

    return a;


}

int main() {

    int t,n;
    std::vector<int> v,ans;
    std::cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        std::cin>>n;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int x;
            std::cin>>x;
            v.push_back(x);
        }

        ans=reversearray(v,n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            std::cout<<ans[i]<<" ";

        //Simple solution would be to iterate in reverse order
        /*for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            cout<<v[i]<<" ";
        }*/

        std::cout<<"\n";

        v.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**GFG Verdict:**

[image]

**If you want to use `v[i]`:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> reversearray(std::vector<int> a,int n)
{
    int low=0, high=n-1;

    while(low<high)
    {
        std::swap(a[low],a[high]);
        low++;
        high--;
    }

    return a;


}

int main() {

    int t,n;
    std::vector<int> v,ans;
    std::cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        std::cin>>n;

        v.resize(n);

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            std::cin>>v[i];
        }

        ans=reversearray(v,n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            std::cout<<ans[i]<<" ";

        //Simple solution would be to iterate in reverse order
        /*for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            cout<<v[i]<<" ";
        }*/

        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

**PS:** I would suggest not using **bits/stdc++.h** and **using namespace std**. You can find out the reason why.

Comment: But why we can't use v[i]? please can you explain where it is initialized to 0.

Comment: But why do we need to resize it since in arrays we never do it.Can you explain the concept behind it.

Comment: but its dynamic array, it does allocate memory by itself, also Iupvoted but 15 reputations are required for me.

Comment: can you answer this but its dynamic array, it does allocate memory by itself?

Comment: Run this code here at https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/reverse-an-array/0/?track=PC-W2-A&batchId=131 it gives test case failed please update code according to that.

Comment: I have corrected the code. Added v.clear() for each test case. Also shared the GFG verdict as it gives correct answer for both the codes.